# how to resize image inside "embed" tag without make it cropped?

Tags: image, svg, width

how can I place "svg" animation in a webpage and make it work on all browsers?

I try to place "SVG" animation on my website,
but when I do it with "img" the animation doesn't work.

The picture shows but without animation.
I want the animation to show.

So I did it with "embed" tag and it works.
But.. it can't be resized. When I change the width, it is getting cropped instead of resized..

Same result with "object" tag..

How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Add a viewBox attribute to the root svg element

Comment: i have a file "mypic.svg" and thats it.
i dont know what is "viewbox" and what is "root svg element"

Comment: You can search for those thing and read up now you know though can't you.